# Geometrical meaning of multiplying a non negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given two square matrix $X,A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$

$Y = A^TX$

What is the geometrical meaning of $Y$ if $X$ is non negative?

What properties can we claim from $Y$?

Comment: You can't say anything without more information (about $A$, say).

Comment: When you say non-negative, do you mean [non-negative definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix)?

Comment: I mean entry-wise non-negativity.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that a matrix having a non-negative matrix as a factor confers any geometric consequences upon $Y$. Since $A$ could be anything, it could wildy change the behavior of $Y$.

Even if you just focus on $X$, $X$ may have conjugate matrices which are not positive in all entries. Consequently, it isn't an invariant of the transformation $X$ represents.  Since geometry is founded upon the behavior of transformations of the space, this makes it unlikely that the positivity of the matrix plays a large geometric role.

On the other hand, the [Perron Frobenius theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) *is* able to conclude something about eigenvalues of positive matrices, so one could try to draw some geometric conclusion from that.

Mainly I think positive matrices are largely in the domain of probability and dynamical systems theorists, and I'm not too sure how strongly geometry plays a role there.

Comment: Are we sure that 'non-negative' means 'has non-negative entries'?  If so, the OP should state this explicitly; I would interpret 'non-negative' to mean non-negative as an operator on $\mathbb{R}^N$ with the standard inner product (especially as geometry is mentioned).

Comment: @Rhys OP confirmed that he means entrywise non-negativity (although yes, I did not think of this possible difference in interpretations ahead of time: I got lucky.)